# How / should I set entity fields that are read only for test purposes?

Tags: java, hibernate

This isn't about a recent problem, more like one from history which I think I just found at least one answer to. I was working in a shop wherein the Architect insisted on having many fields of our entities read-only, i.e. without setters of any sort. I mean we were using Hibernate and obviously you can annotate the fields as read only...but his requirement was to eliminate the setters so they couldn't ever be set without using Reflection. He even wrote a suite of utilities that used Reflection to set those fields for testing and you had to extend them if there were changes to your schema. My problem with this was that it was dog slow and a big bunch of seemingly unnecessary code that was always changing. Mocks could be used of course but those can get painful as well if your data is non-trivial. Now I just found something that looks like a good answer but I would like to hear from the community as it may not be the best answer. For one thing, I question if we should have even been doing that.

Comment: Sounds like static final fields could have been used

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways:

- mocks - the simplest, e.g. Mockito library;
- builders - setters only + validation on build;
- package-local setters + same-package factories in tests scope.

Do NOT use:

- 100500 constructor arguments - this way leads to extremely hard-to-support code.

Builders example:

```
interface Model (
    A getA();
    ...
)
public final class ModelBuilder {
    private ModelBuilder() {...}
    public static ModelBuilder newBuilder() {...}

    public ModelBuilder setA(A a) (...) // keep 'a', return 'this'
    ...
    public Model build() {...}
}
```

Comment: Mocks were excluded in the question due to complexity of the model. Imagine being 15 mocks wide and deep for some 50 odd classes.  Not sure what you mean by Builders. Can you elaborate? Package local setters.... I actually tried to go that route. Architect said, "No." Have you heard about this Spring utility called "ReflectionTestUtils"?  Look here: 
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/unit-testing.html ( 13.2.1 General testing utilities )

Comment: I know spring RefTestUtils. Mocks are much simpler in use. There are two cases, when it is hard to use mocks: bad app design and incorrect testing approach. I saw both problems (bank application, 300+ developers, very complex models). And I agree with your architect - there is no need in public setters.

Comment: I don't disagree with him except in that it makes things really tough in those problem environments. If your using hibernate anyway, one might substitute a Hypersonic instance for the actual database for testing... or if you need the real McCoy then you could keep a copy of the schema in Hypersonic. You could initialize mocks by using a database with records that contain the values you want. ...or maybe you could us DBUnit to create them. Meh... It's pretty involved though.

Comment: Some might say that you don't need a real database to test against but I've had it to many times where someone changed the DB without informing Dev.  If you use a real DB for testing, you find these things out a lot sooner.